# Azure Databricks: Error with custom library on cluster in VNet

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-virtual-network

We are using Azure Databricks with a single-node cluster in a VNet (Runtime Version 10.4 LTS).
We also need to use a custom/private python module (wheel).

After the library is installed on the cluster, everything is working fine, but after the cluster is restarted and the library installed, the following error appears on the execution of **any** cell (de-/reattaching doesn't solve the issue):

```
+ Failure starting repl. Try detaching and re-attaching the notebook.

java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$withClient$2(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.maybeSynchronized(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$withClient$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:150)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:364)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$resourceLoader$1(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.client$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.client(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.$anonfun$addJar$1(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.$anonfun$addJar$1$adapted(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:163)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionResourceLoader.addJar(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AddJarsCommand.$anonfun$run$1(resources.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AddJarsCommand.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(resources.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.AddJarsCommand.run(resources.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:541)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.&lt;init&gt;(Dataset.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:793)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:788)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:695)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$new$3(DriverLocal.scala:267)
    at com.databricks.sql.acl.CheckPermissions$.trusted(CheckPermissions.scala:1566)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$new$2(DriverLocal.scala:267)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.&lt;init&gt;(DriverLocal.scala:250)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.&lt;init&gt;(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:152)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.&lt;init&gt;(PythonDriverLocal.scala:73)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverWrapper.instantiateDriver(DriverWrapper.scala:697)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.setupRepl(DriverWrapper.scala:335)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:224)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.databaseExists(Hive.java:1154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_12.databaseExists(HiveShim.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:435)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$retryLocked$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.synchronizeOnObject(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(PoolingHiveClient.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.$anonfun$databaseExists$1$adapted(PoolingHiveClient.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.withHiveClient(PoolingHiveClient.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.PoolingHiveClient.databaseExists(PoolingHiveClient.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:300)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$withClient$2(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:151)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.&lt;init&gt;(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1165)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Error creating transactional connection factory
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:671)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:830)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:334)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.&lt;init&gt;(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.&lt;init&gt;(HiveMetaStore.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.&lt;init&gt;(RetryingHMSHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:4944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.&lt;init&gt;(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:171)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:203)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.&lt;init&gt;(AbstractStoreManager.java:162)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.&lt;init&gt;(RDBMSStoreManager.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:422)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:817)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Attempt to invoke the &quot;HikariCP&quot; plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : Failed to initialize pool: Could not connect to address=(host=prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:232)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.&lt;init&gt;(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Failed to initialize pool: Could not connect to address=(host=prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:512)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.&lt;init&gt;(HikariPool.java:105)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.&lt;init&gt;(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:176)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    ... 147 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Could not connect to address=(host=prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com)(port=3306)(type=master) : prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:175)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:83)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1111)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:502)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:155)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:341)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:506)
    ... 151 more
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:445)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1103)
    ... 158 more
```

This is independent if the custom module is imported/used, even if the custom library has no real code inside. Modules from PyPI work fine, though.

We could narrow it down to the activation of the VNet feature. Are there configurations or script to bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have configure Network Security Group rules according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject#network-security-group-rules-for-workspaces-created-after-january-13-2020), specifically that you don't block traffic on port 3306. You also need to check that your user-defined routes or firewall are configured correctly and don't block outgoing traffic to the built-in Hive metastore - the host name & IP address are specific to the region and could be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/udr#--metastore-artifact-blob-storage-log-blob-storage-and-event-hub-endpoint-ip-addresses).

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. The problem was the assignment of the NSG with the right ports to the Subnet

Comment: An additional problem was the DNS configuration for the private vnet. The domain `database.windows.net` was used, which made the resolution for `prod-metastore.mysql.database.azure.com` impossible. We switched the private zone (as the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns) state) to `privatelink.database.windows.net`